# Is Bi-directional Communication with Long-Lived Serving Code Supported in Knative?

Tags: knative, knative-serving

I’d like to setup a Knative Serving for a bunch of revisions (50k, most of them scaled to 0)
The serving code will be fairly long-lived, up to 1 min, and bi-directionally communicate with a caller.
It’d be great if one bi-directional session would be counted as concurrency = 1.

Is this supported?
Would protocol would be better? Pure http/2, gRPC, websocket?

So far I tried to look for the solution in the docs. No luck.